# html5sql.js inserting is very slow with Android Honeycomb and ICS

Tags: javascript, android, sql

I'm using html5sql javascript library (html5sql.js) to speed up multiple inserts into HTML5 database on Android with Phonegap. It seems to be very fast with Android 2.X (1000 rows in 1 second) but it's very slow with Android 3.X and 4.X (1000 rows in few minutes). Does anyone know the solution?

My code fragment:

```
sqlStatements = 'INSERT INTO table ("id","data") VALUES("' + id + '", "' + data + '"); INSERT INTO ... ' // 1 thousand inserts 
html5sql.openDatabase(
         "dbase",
         "dbase",
         3*1024*1024);

html5sql.process(
            //This is the text data from the SQL file you retrieved
            sqlStatements,
            function(){
                // After all statements are processed this function will be called.
                console.log("success ");
            },
            function(error){
                // Handle any errors here
                console.log("error " + error);
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running "PRAGMA synchronous=OFF;PRAGMA count_changes=OFF;PRAGMA journal_mode=MEMORY;PRAGMA temp_store=MEMORY;" before the first sql query

Comment: I have found that your hint is usable with standard inserting method e.g. tx.executeSql(INSERT INTO ...) but doesn't work with html5sql.js library. Of course html5sql.js is much more faster than tx.executeSql().